# Can we use TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT to make user interactive view above locked screen?

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

I have checked out almost all the questions regarding this but couldn't find my solution, because:

1. I don't want to use `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR` for the standards of my app.
2. The screen must not be unlocked.
3. I want something that Whatsapp uses for its incoming call.

Comment: let me know if i could do the same using TYPE_PRIORITY_PHONE.